# Sessions with php and Zend, Failed to write session data

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, xampp

First of all I have to ask sorry for my english, that's not so good but I hope you'll understand.
I started studying Zend framework, I have a problem with sessions, but I think that's not related with zend...
anyway i have an error message when I use:

`$risultato=$auth->authenticate($adapter);`

On my login page I have this message:

`Message: Zend_Session::start() - C:\ZendFramework-1.12.0\library\Zend\Session.php(Line:477): Error #2 session_start(): open(C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendDue\application/../data/session\sess_4beo9fvfqenb6s2b67q5cj5ap6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) C:\ZendFramework-1.12.0\library\Zend\Session.php(Line:487): Error #2 session_write_close(): open(C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendDue\application/../data/session\sess_4beo9fvfqenb6s2b67q5cj5ap6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) C:\ZendFramework-1.12.0\library\Zend\Session.php(Line:487): Error #2 session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendDue\application/../data/session)`

I'm using xampp and in php.ini file I have
`session.save_path = "C:\xampp\tmp"`

I don't know what to do, I'm getting depressed because of this, right now I thought I had understood...

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Do you know what "no such file or directory" means?  Does the directory exist?

Comment: i just solved creating folder data and under data the folder session, now it works perfectly!! i see the raccomended structure folder and i see that i didn't had these folsers..